# How do I clear duplicate spaces In string

Tags: c#, vb.net

```vb
dim a as string = "     wilcome      to  sa      WeCame    "
```

The desired result :

```
"Wilcome to sa WeCame"
```

Comment: Regex will do it for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Dim a As String = "     wilcome      to  sa      WeCame    "
Dim cleanedString As String = Regex.Replace(a, "\s{2,}", " ").Trim()
```

Comment: That leaves a space at the start and end. I suggest using .Trim() for simplicity: `Regex.Replace(a.Trim(), "\s{2,}", " ")`.

Comment: That was my first thought as well but it won’t work.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Just to make it clear to anyone reading this, Konrad's comment applies to the suggested answer which does not have .Trim() in it, and not to my comment - there was only one second between the comment posting times.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string and assemble it again. It is worth noting that there is an overload of the [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-method that allows you to specify options that change the behavior when splitting strings. In this case, [StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) should be specified:

```
Dim a As String = "     wilcome      to  sa      WeCame    "
Dim parts = a.Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim result = String.Join(" ", parts)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do most text manipulations is via [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). In .NET, the regex library can be found under `System.Text.RegularExpressions`. Make sure to learn at least the basics of that, it’s an indispensable tool for programmers.

The basic pattern to match two or more spaces is fairly simple: `"  +"`. That is: one space, plus at least one more. Another way of writing this is `" {2,}"`. Here’s the result:

```vb
dim a = "     wilcome      to  sa      WeCame    "
dim result = Regex.Replace(a, "  +", " ")
```

Unfortunately, that won’t be enough:

```vb
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", result)
' [ wilcome to sa WeCame ]
```

There are redundant spaces at both ends of the stirng. Now, we can get (almost) arbitrarily fancy in regex and it’s absolutely possible to fix our expression to take care of that.<sup>1</sup> However, there’s a much more straightforward way: `Trim()` the resulting string:

```vb
dim result = Regex.Replace(a, "  +", " ").Trim()
```

Simplicity beats cleverness any day of the week. And today is Friday.

---

<sup>1</sup> Just for fun, here’s a way:

```vb
dim result = Regex.Replace(text, "((^) +)|( +($))|(( ) +)", "$2$4$6")
```

This uses the fact that using parentheses in a regular expression in .NET *captures* the matched text corresponding to the content inside the parentheses. In the replacement string, we can then insert that captured part.

The second piece in the puzzle is that `^` matches a the start position of the string, and `$` matches at the end. That way, we have three alternatives: either match the start of the string followed by spaces, or match the end, preceded by spaces, or match one space followed by more spaces. And then replace all that by the start, or one space (depending on what was matched).